# Only returning first word before space when running GET request from mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

**Background:**

I am working on a mini crud project learning how to incorporate CRUD with node.js and mysql. For this section I am pulling the data that will populate several input fields so I can make some changes then update.

**Problem:**

Everything is working fine it is just when I run the *GET* request the data I get back is everything before the first space. So if I have a product called **ALL Clear** I will only get the result **ALL** this is the same for every field.

**Goal:**

My goal is to get the full text into my input fields rather than a partial.

Here is my server.js code that shows my GET request which includes to html code that will render showing all the inputs populated with the data from mysql:

**What I have done:**

I have done research but am only finding references to PHP for some reason

```
 app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
    let ID = req.query.ID;
    let option = req.query.selectpicker;
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM ' + option + ' WHERE id=' + ID, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var html = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <title>Update Item</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 class="bg-dark p-3 text-center text-white">UPDATE ITEM</h1>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 pt-5 container font-weight-bold">
    `;
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    html += `<form class="contact_section_form pt-3 pb-3">`
    html += `<div class="form-group">`
    html += `<label class="font-weight-bold">Option</label>`
    html += `<input type="input" class="form-control" name="selectpicker" value=${option} readonly>`
    html += `</div>`
    html += `<div class="form-group">`
    html += `<label class="font-weight-bold">Id</label>`
    html += `<input type="input" class="form-control" name="idName" value=${result[i].id} readonly>`
    html += `</div>`
    html += `<div class="form-group">`
    html += `<label class="font-weight-bold">Supply Name</label>`
    html += `<input type="input" class="form-control" name="supplyName" value=${result[i].supply_name} readonly>`
    html += `</div>`
    html += `<div class="form-group">`
    html += `<label class="font-weight-bold">Description</label>`
    html += `<input type="input" class="form-control" name="descriptionInfo" value=${result[i].description_info} readonly>`
    html += `</div>`
    html += `<div class="form-group">`
    html += `<label class="font-weight-bold">Quantity</label>`
    html += `<input type="input" class="form-control" name="quantity" value=${result[i].qty}>`
    html += `</div>`
    html += `<div class="form-group">`
    html += `<label class="font-weight-bold">Size</label>`
    html += `<input type="input" class="form-control" name="size" value=${result[i].size }>`
    html += `</div>`
    html += `<div class="form-group">`
    html += `<label class="font-weight-bold">Amount</label>`
    html += `<input type="input" class="form-control" name="amount" value=${result[i].amount}>`
    html += `</div>`
    html += `<div class="form-group">`
    html += `<label class="font-weight-bold">Unit Of Measurement</label>`
    html += `<input type="input" class="form-control" name="unitOfMeasurement" value=${result[i].unit_of_measurement}>`
    html += `</div>`
    html += `<div class="form-group">`
    html += `<label class="font-weight-bold">Category</label>`
    html += `<input type="input" class="form-control" name="category" value=${result[i].category} readonly>`
    html += `</div>`
    html += `<div class="form-group">`
    html += `<label class="font-weight-bold">Category Id</label>`
    html += `<input type="input" class="form-control" name="categoryId" value=${result[i].category_id} readonly>`
    html += `</div>`
    html += `<div class="form-group">`
    html += `<label class="font-weight-bold">Date received</label>`
    html += `<input type="input" class="form-control" name="dateReceived" value=${result[i].date_received} readonly>`
    html += `</div>`
    html += `<div class="form-group">`
    html += `<label class="font-weight-bold">Last date removed</label>`
    html += `<input type="input" class="form-control" name="lastDateRemoved" value=${result[i].last_date_removed} readonly>`
    html += `</div>`
    html += `<div class="text-center">`
    html += `<button class="btn btn-md btn-secondary font-weight-bold text-uppercase" formmethod="POST" formaction="/update">Update</button>`
    html += `</div>`
    html += `</form>`
    }
    html += `</body>`
    html += `</html>`
    res.send(html);
    });
    });
```

Here is what an example looks like when the data is pulled into the input forms:

[image: first]

And here is a picture of the database in this example you can see that the item we used for the image above says ***Toilet Paper*** but it is only pulling ***Toilet***

Any guidance or feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting quotes around all your `value` attributes, something like this.

```
 html += `<input type="input" class="form-control" 
     name="supplyName" 
     value="${result[i].supply_name}" readonly>`
           ^                        ^
```

But, it's a little more complex than that, because it's possible your database column values themselves contain `"` characters. Putting them literally into your html will foul it up. Try this:

```
 html += `<input type="input" class="form-control" 
     name="supplyName" 
     value="${escape(result[i].supply_name)}" readonly>`
           ^  ^^^^^^^                     ^ ^
```

**Pro tip** Using a HTML template engine like [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) or [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) will make your life much easier once you figure it out.

**Pro tip** `View source ...` in your browser is your friend.

Comment: Thank you so much.